# Употребление слова "вперекрут"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Тип завёртки - в перекрут (или вперекрут, или просто - перекрут)?

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно этого слова в словарях не нашла. Но можно посмотреть на аналогичные наречия: *вперекрест, вперекидку, вперегиб, вперевёрт, вперевёртку, впереворот* и др. (см. Полный орфографический словарь русского языка под ред. Лопатина). Я бы, опираясь на аналогию, написала это наречие слитно: *вперекрут*.